# django + celery + uwsgi without supervisor

Tags: django, celery, uwsgi, django-celery

On dev server Django is working well with celery and django-celery:

```
python manage.py runserver
celery -A backup worker -l info -B
celerycam --frequency=10.0
```

On production server I tried to run celery with:

```
[uwsgi]
...
master = True
smart-attach-daemon = ${path}/${name_project}/.env/bin/python ${path}/manage.py celery -A test worker -l info -B
smart-attach-daemon = ${path}/${name_project}/.env/bin/python ${path}/manage.py celerycam --frequency=10.0
```

But it does not work.
How can I run it all without the use supervisor?

**Update**

It does not see Django, but the site works. In logs uwsgi:

```
Mon Aug  3 16:10:57 2015 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 23462)
Mon Aug  3 16:10:57 2015 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 23666, cores: 1)
Mon Aug  3 16:10:57 2015 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 23667, cores: 1)
Mon Aug  3 16:10:57 2015 - [uwsgi-daemons] spawning "/home/1/2/3/manage.py celery -A backup worker -l info -B"
Mon Aug  3 16:10:57 2015 - [uwsgi-daemons] spawning "/home/1/2/3/manage.py celerycam --frequency=10.0"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/1/2/3/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/1/2/3/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
Mon Aug  3 16:10:58 2015 - subprocess 23668 exited with code 1
Mon Aug  3 16:10:58 2015 - subprocess 23669 exited with code 1
```

manage.py:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backup.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Log output? What version of uWSGI are you using—does it support smart daemons?

Comment: Added logs uwsgi. uWSGI 1.9.17.1-debian (64bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "smart-attach-daemon" on "attach-daemon"

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `attach-daemon` or `smart-attach-daemon`. But if you are using smart-attach-daemon then you should also start celery with pid file and set path to it in uwsgi:

```
smart-attach-daemon = ${path}/${name_project}/var/celery-worker.pid ${path}/${name_project}/.env/bin/python ${path}/manage.py celery -A test worker --pidfile=${path}/${name_project}/var/celery-worker.pid  -l info -B
```